# Measuring time in millisecond precision

Tags: c, time

My program is going to race different sorting algorithms against each other, both in time and space.  I've got space covered, but measuring time is giving me some trouble.  Here is the code that runs the sorts:

```
void test(short* n, short len) {
  short i, j, a[1024];

  for(i=0; i<2; i++) {         // Loop over each sort algo
    memused = 0;               // Initialize memory marker
    for(j=0; j<len; j++)       // Copy scrambled list into fresh array
      a[j] = n[j];             // (Sorting algos are in-place)
                               // ***Point A***
    switch(i) {                // Pick sorting algo
    case 0:
      selectionSort(a, len);
    case 1:
      quicksort(a, len);
    }
                               // ***Point B***    
    spc[i][len] = memused;     // Record how much mem was used
  }
}
```

(I removed some of the sorting algos for simplicity)

Now, I need to measure how much time the sorting algo takes.  The most obvious way to do this is to record the time at point (a) and then subtract that from the time at point (b).  But none of the C time functions are good enough:

**time()** gives me time in seconds, but the algos are faster than that, so I need something more accurate.

**clock()** gives me CPU ticks since the program started, but seems to round to the nearest 10,000; still not small enough

The **time** shell command works well enough, except that I need to run over 1,000 tests per algorithm, and I need the individual time for each one.

I have no idea what **getrusage()** returns, but it's also too long.

What I need is time in units (significantly, if possible) smaller than the run time of the sorting functions: about 2ms.  So my question is:  Where can I get that?

Comment: Which platform?  Mentioning [`getrusage()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrusage.html) suggests a POSIX system, in which case [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) or [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) is appropriate (microsecond and nanosecond resolution, respectively, not necessarily with the stated accuracy).

Comment: `man 2 clock_gettime`, or, if you can use C 2011, `int timespec_get(struct timespec *ts, int base);`

Comment: Platform:  AMD Athlon 64 (Running Debian Linux)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) has microseconds resolution and is easy to use.

A pair of useful timer functions is:

```
static struct timeval tm1;

static inline void start()
{
    gettimeofday(&tm1, NULL);
}

static inline void stop()
{
    struct timeval tm2;
    gettimeofday(&tm2, NULL);

    unsigned long long t = 1000 * (tm2.tv_sec - tm1.tv_sec) + (tm2.tv_usec - tm1.tv_usec) / 1000;
    printf("%llu ms\n", t);
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Unfortunately no, but at least it *generally* provides a good approximation. Of course these 10 or so lines don't make good production code, but that wasn't my goal either.

Comment: Microseconds is `µs` (using ascii code 230 -- `'\181'` in octal), not `ms` (which stands for milliseconds).  It's commonly written with a `u` instead of a *mu*: `us`.

Comment: @paddy Euh... did I assert something that opposes that?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I misread and thought you were outputting microseconds.

Comment: Yeah, do not use `gettimeofday`. It is subject to time server updates and drift.

Answer (score 10):

For measuring time, use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` if it is available). Where possible, avoid using `gettimeofday`. It is specifically deprecated in favor of `clock_gettime`, and the time returned from it is subject to adjustments from time servers, which can throw off your measurements.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the total user + kernel time (or choose just one) using `getrusage` as follows:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

double get_process_time() {
    struct rusage usage;
    if( 0 == getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage) ) {
        return (double)(usage.ru_utime.tv_sec + usage.ru_stime.tv_sec) +
               (double)(usage.ru_utime.tv_usec + usage.ru_stime.tv_usec) / 1.0e6;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I elected to create a `double` containing fractional seconds...

```
double t_begin, t_end;

t_begin = get_process_time();
// Do some operation...
t_end = get_process_time();

printf( "Elapsed time: %.6f seconds\n", t_end - t_begin );
```

Answer (score 2):

The Time Stamp Counter could be helpful here:

```
static unsigned long long rdtsctime() {
    unsigned int eax, edx;
    unsigned long long val;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=a"(eax), "=d"(edx));
    val = edx;
    val = val << 32;
    val += eax;
    return val;
}
```

Though there are some caveats to this. The timestamps for different processor cores may be different, and changing clock speeds (due to power saving features and the like) can cause erroneous results.

Comment: Assuming you're on an Intel/AMD x86_64 platform, not SPARC, PPC, PA-RISC (and probably not IA-64 either).

Comment: I believe from Pentium 4 onward, the TSC is independent of the instantaneous CPU frequency (see chapter 17.12 of the Intel-64 SDM).

Comment: There is no need for CPU specific instructions to solve the original question above, even if an Intel based system is being used.  Comparing sort algorithms does not require this type of granularity (at all) if done properly.